# Affine embedding of the two-point lattice into a semiring-like structure

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

A **commutative semiring-like** structure is a structure $(R, {+}, {\cdot})$ where $+$ and $\cdot$ are associative and commutative, and $\cdot$ distributes over $+$.

Is there a commutative semiring-like $R$ such that we can embed the two element lattice $\{\bot, \top\}$ into $R$ so that meet and join are affine mappings? More precisely, we seek a semirig $R$ with distinct elements $F, T \in R$ such that, for some $a, b, c \in R$ we have the "truth table for disjunction"
\begin{align*}
a \cdot F + b \cdot F + c &= F \\
a \cdot F + b \cdot T + c &= T \\
a \cdot T + b \cdot F + c &= T \\
a \cdot T + b \cdot T + c &= T
\end{align*}
and there are some $d, e, f \in R$ that give us the "truth table for conjunction":
\begin{align*}
d \cdot F + e \cdot F + f &= F \\
d \cdot F + e \cdot T + f &= F \\
d \cdot T + e \cdot F + f &= F \\
d \cdot T + e \cdot T + f &= T ?
\end{align*}
A cursory search reveals that no such structure of size 2, 3, 4 or 5 exists.

**Supplemental:** Ludwig Maes, who originally asked me this question, observes that
\begin{align*}
  F + F &= (d \cdot F + e \cdot T + f) + (d \cdot T + e \cdot F + f) \\
        &= (d \cdot T + e \cdot T + f) + (d \cdot F + e \cdot F + f) \\
        &= T + F.
\end{align*}
Thus, if there is such a structure, it can't have good cancellation properties, or at least $F$ and $T$ should not, or else we get $F = T$. This rules out all rings, for example.

**Additional question:** It turns out the original question did not assume commutativity of $\cdot$ (in which case we assume both the left and right distributivity of $\cdot$ over $+$). It would be interesting to have an answer also for the non-commutative case. Unfortunately, Keith Kearnes's beautiful use of the majorit function does not work without commutativity of $\cdot$.

Comment: Why give semiring a new name 'semirig' or am I missing something new? or just typo?

Comment: Doesn't a semiring have a unit for $+$? Maybe a "non-unital semiring"? I can fix the question if there is an established name for these.

Comment: "unital" would refer to the multiplicative unit

Comment: Yes, so what do we call this thing?

Comment: Do you need a finite one? Because otherwise one might just take the quotient of ${\mathbb N}[F,T,a,b,c,d,e,f]$ by the congruence generated by these equations.

Comment: And we know that the quotient is non-trivial?

Comment: Nothing up to size 5, by the way.

Comment: Andrej, it's hard to think of a more confusing terminology. Anybody reading "semirig" would think of a typo with missing n, or even not notice the typo and read "ring". Can't you coin another word? (I found some occurrences of "semirig", which are indeed typos for semiring: http://www.ejpam.com/index.php/ejpam/article/viewFile/1242/213, http://www.labri.fr/perso/slombard/publi/Der.pdf, http://www.math.uaic.ro/~annalsmath/pdf-uri%20anale/F1(2009)/Dhara.pdf)

Comment: @YCor The term "rig" is actually pretty well-established: https://www.google.com/search?q=rig+%28mathematics%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=rig+ring+without+negatives  It's certainly *very* commonplace in the categorical community (and "semirig" in that community means what Andrej says, although it's perhaps not quite as commonly used).

Comment: Dang, the original question did not assume commutativity of $\cdot$. Apologies! Can anyone come up with an answer where multiplication is not assumed to be commutative?

Comment: I replaced the confusing term with "semiring-like structure". It wasn't really a semirig anyway.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I searched "semirig" in Google (with quotation marks since instead Google corrects) and only found apparent typos. Commonplace doesn't mean good terminology although it's the first time I can think of a terminology which is bad for this very reason. (In a similar vein, one coauthor once reproched me to use $A$ and $\mathsf{A}$ for distinct meanings in the same place and for him it was energy-consuming to distinguish.) Here in addition "semirig" was in the same sentence as the word "distributres". Maybe "distributres" is commonplace in categorical community too? :)

Comment: Acknowledged - as the answer shows, that congruence quotient is actually trivial. Now concerning the noncommutative case - there are then more kinds of affine operations, like $aXb+cY+Xd+Y+e$, etc. - are all of them accepted?

Comment: @YCor I can't tell whether you're complaining about "rig" as well, but I don't think that one's bad (at least it's an English word, and it's also memorable once you get the pun). "Semiring" by analogy with "semigroup" would actually be the right word for Andrej's thingies (no negatives, no $0$), but for the fact that the word is already taken and is defined to mean that $0$ is included. A pity!

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Hi, I originally posed the question, sadly the coefficients stay on the left side in multiplication. Please note I am not a mathematician, I was somewhat curious what you meant with "just take the quotient of N[F,T,a,b,c,d,e,f] by the congruence generated by these equations" ? My concept of quotients and congruence is limited to simple examples like $\mathbb{Z}$ being like $\mathbb{N}^2$ with equivalence classes $x_1+y_2=x_2+y_1$? The original question can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299390/a-model-for-a-theory-supporting-and-and-or + nice proof Keith!

Comment: @propaganda Let me answer at the math.SE page that you link to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no commutative semiring with the desired
properties.

To see this, suppose instead that the semiring
$R$ contains a subset $\{F, T\}$ supporting affine operations
$\vee, \wedge$ that are lattice operations on $\{F, T\}$.
$R$ then has 
an affine operation
$m(x,y,z) := (x\wedge y)\vee (x\wedge z)\vee (y\wedge z)$ that is a majority operation on $\{F, T\}$.
Let $m(x,y,z)=A_1x+A_2y+A_3z+B$ be an affine representation for
this operation.
By comparing coefficients and constant terms, observe that

$$
m(m(x_{11},x_{12},x_{13}),m(x_{21},x_{22},x_{23}),m(x_{31},x_{32},x_{33}))\\
=
m(m(x_{11},x_{21},x_{31}),m(x_{12},x_{22},x_{32}),m(x_{13},x_{23},x_{33}))
$$

holds throughout $R$.
(Specifically, the coefficient of $x_{ij}$ on either side is $A_iA_j$,
while the constant term on either side is $A_1B+A_2B+A_3B+B$.)

But under the substitution
$x_{11}=x_{12}=x_{22}=x_{23}=T$ and
$x_{13}=x_{21}=x_{31}=x_{32}=x_{33}=F$
the left side gives $T$ while the right side gives $F$ (since $m(x,y,z)$
acts like majority on $\{F, T\}$).
This is a contradiction. $\Box$

---

**edit 6/23/17.**

The question was edited to ask

**Is there a *noncommutative* semiring $R$
such that we can embed the 2-element lattice
into $R$ so that meet and join are affine mappings?**

Let me explain how to convert
this question to a more tractable one, and then I will
answer the tractable version.

---

Conversion:

Part 1.
An algebra $A$ is embeddable in a **semiring**
so that its operations have **affine**
polynomial representations iff
$A$ is embeddable in a **semimodule**
so that its operations have 
polynomial representations. (Here to **embed** $A$
means to represent $A$
as a subalgebra of a reduct of the polynomial
expansion.)

[Reasoning: If $A$ is affinely embeddable in a semiring $R$,
view $R$ as a semimodule over itself to get $A$ embedded
in a semimodule. For the other direction, if $A$
is embedded in an $S$-semimodule $M$, can affinely embed
$A$ in the matrix semiring 
$\left[\begin{matrix} S&M\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]$.]

Part 2.
The 2-element lattice is embeddable in a semimodule
iff the 2-element majority algebra is embeddable.

[Reasoning:
If $\{T,F\}$ supports lattice polynomials $\vee, \wedge$,
then it supports a majority polynomial
$m(x,y,z) = (x\vee y)\wedge (x\vee z)\wedge (y\vee z)$.
Conversely, if $\{T,F\}$ supports a majority polynomial
$m(x,y,z)$, then it supports lattice polynomials
$x\vee y = m(x,y,T)$ and $x\wedge y = m(x,y,F)$.]

---

I reformulate the edited question as:

**Is there a semimodule $M$ over a *noncommutative*
semiring $R$
such that we can embed the 2-element majority
algebra into $M$ as a subalgebra of a reduct
of the polynomial expansion?**

Answers: 
(1) Yes, it **is** possible
to embed the 2-element majority algebra into a semimodule,
but (2) not into a finite semimodule.

The explanation of why it is possible
to embed the 2-element majority algebra into a semimodule
can be found in

Jaroslav Jezek,
Terms and semiterms,
Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae
**20** (1979), 447-460.

In this paper it is shown that **every algebra is embeddable
in a semimodule**.
(Hence every algebra is affinely embeddable in a semiring.)

---

However, it is **not** possible to embed the 2-element majority
algebra into a **finite** semimodule. (Equivalently,
it is not possible to embed the
2-element lattice into a finite
semiring so that its operations have affine
polynomial representations.)

This can be proved by modifying my proof for the commutative case.
The modification is a bit long, but I will include it
here for those who want to check.

**Proof** (That you can't embed the 2-element majority
algebra into a finite semimodule.)

Assume that $M$ is a finite semimodule over the semiring
$R$, which we may assume acts faithfully on $M$.
The faithfulness assumption forces $R$ to be finite as well.
Assume also that the semimodule polynomial
$m(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z + d$ acts like
a majority operation on
the set $\{T, F\}\subseteq M$.

Call $m^{(2)}(x,y,z):=
m(m(x,y,z),y,z)$ the 2nd first-variable iterate of $m$,
$m^{(3)}(x,y,z):=m(m(m(x,y,z),y,z),y,z)$ the 3rd
first-variable iterate of $m$, ETC. Each $m^{(k)}(x,y,z)$
is a majority polynomial on $\{T,F\}$, and has the form
$\alpha^{(k)} x + \beta^{(k)} y + \gamma^{(k)} z + d^{(k)}$.
I may select any one of these to be my
majority polynomial as I continue the argument.

Since we are iterating in the first variable, $\alpha^{(k)} = \alpha^k$.
Since $M$ is a semimodule over a finite semiring,
it is possible to choose $k$ so that $\alpha^{2k}=\alpha^k$.
This allows me to replace the original majority polynomial with 
some first variable iterate, change notation back,
and henceforth assume that the majority polynomial
$m(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z + d$
was selected to satisfy $\alpha^2=\alpha$.
(This is where the finiteness is used!)

Now $T=m(T,F,T)=\alpha T + (\beta F + \gamma T + d)$ is not equal to
$F=m(F,F,T)=\alpha F + (\beta F + \gamma T + d)$, so 
necessarily $\alpha T\neq \alpha F$.
Let $T' = \alpha T$ and $F' = \alpha F$. I claim that

there are inverse semimodule polynomial bijections
$f\colon\{T, F\}\to \{T',F'\}$ and
$g\colon\{T', F'\}\to \{T,F\}$,

these bijections allow us to conjugate $m$ to a majority
polynomial $\mu (x,y,z):=f(m(g(x),g(y),g(z))$ on $\{T', F'\}$,

$\mu (x,y,z)$ can be further modified to a majority 
polynomial $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)$
on $\{T',F'\}$ where the coefficient of $x$ commutes with the
coefficients of $y$ and $z$, and finally

this is enough commutativity to make the proof
for the commutative case work here.

To establish the first bulleted item,
let $f(x)=\alpha x$ and $g(x)=x+\beta F+\gamma T+d$.
That $f\colon \{T, F\}\to \{T',F'\}$ is a bijection follows from the
definitions of $T'$ and $F'$. That $g\colon\{T', F'\}\to \{T,F\}$
is the inverse follows from the majority equations for $m$.

The second bulleted item follows from the fact that conjugation
preserves the majority identities.

For the third bulleted item, it is easy to see that the coefficient
of $x$ in $\mu (x,y,z) = f(m(g(x),g(y),g(z))$ is $\alpha^2 = \alpha$.
That is, $\mu (x,y,z) = \alpha x + (\textrm{some stuff})$.
If it helps to write it out, we have
$$
\mu(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \alpha \beta y + \alpha\gamma z + D
$$
where
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
D &= \alpha\beta F + \alpha\gamma T + \alpha d + \alpha\beta^2 F
+\alpha\beta\gamma T + \alpha\beta d\\
&+ \alpha\gamma\beta F + \alpha\gamma^2 F
\alpha\gamma^2 T+\alpha\gamma d + \alpha d.
\end{array}
$$

Let $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)=x + \alpha\beta y + \alpha\gamma z + D$.
That is, delete the coefficient
$\alpha$ from $x$ in the polynomial expression
for $\mu(x,y,z)$ (or think of it
as replacing $\alpha$ with $1$).
Observe that the semimodule
polynomials $\mu (x,y,z)$ and $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)$
both have the same restriction to $\{T',F'\} = \{\alpha T, \alpha F\}$,
since the polynomials only differ in their $x$-coefficient,
the inputs all have $\alpha$ as a prefix, and $\alpha^2 = \alpha$.
For example, 
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\overline{\mu}(F',T',T')&=
\overline{\mu}(\alpha F,\alpha T,\alpha T)\\
&=(\alpha F) +
\alpha\beta (\alpha T) + \alpha\gamma (\alpha T) + D\\
&= 
\alpha(\alpha  F) +
\alpha\beta (\alpha T) + \alpha\gamma (\alpha T) + D\\
&= 
\mu(\alpha F,\alpha T,\alpha T)\\
&=
\mu(F',T',T').
\end{array}$$

[Stock-taking:]
We started with the assumption that a $2$-element subset
$\{T, F\}$ of $M$ supports a majority polynomial $m(x,y,z)$,
and constructed a new instance $\{T', F'\}$
and $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)$, but in the latter instance
the coefficient of $x$ commutes with the coefficients of $y$ and $z$
(since in the latter case the coefficient of $x$ is $1$).

Now, modifying the proof in the commutative case, we have
$$
\overline{\mu}
(\overline{\mu}(x_{11},x_{12},x_{13}),\overline{\mu}(x_{21},x_{22},x_{23}),\overline{\mu}(x_{31},x_{32},x_{33}))\\
=
\overline{\mu}
(\overline{\mu}(x_{11},x_{21},x_{31}),\overline{\mu}(x_{12},x_{22},x_{23}),\overline{\mu}(x_{13},x_{32},x_{33})).
$$
But under the substitution $x_{11}=x_{12}=x_{13}=x_{23}=x_{33}=T'$
and $x_{21}=x_{22}=x_{31}=x_{32}=F'$
the left side gives $F'$ while the right side gives $T'$.
$\Box$

Comment: Did you mean *semiring* or *semirig*?

Comment: Whichever you want. The proof only uses plus and times.

Comment: I see that you're not using any property of rings, but still, just to match the questions, you should probably say "there is no semirig with the desired properties" or (better) "there is no such structure".